# How to Limit the Timestamp value upto Seconds?

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp, datetime-format

I need to cut off the millsecond value from my Timestamp value in java .

**For Example:**

```
Timestamp time=2013-09-23 17:57:19.860;
```

**Excepted output:**

```
Time: 2013-09-23 17:57:19
```

Please help me to cut down the milliseconds

Comment: Did you try anything at all?

Comment: http://ideone.com/XCdHQm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     String t = "2013-09-23 17:57:19.860";
     String[] split = t.split(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote("."));
     String result= split[0];
     System.out.println(result);
```

**update**

```
     DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");       
     Date date = dateFormat.parse("2013-09-23 17:57:19.860");
     long time = date.getTime();
     Timestamp timestamp =new Timestamp(time);      
     SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS");
     String result = dateFormat.format(new Date(timestamp.getTime() ));
```

Comment: please say how to cut down from timestamp data type..here it is coded for "string t"

Answer (score 4):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
String date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(time.getDate());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use TimeUnit:

```
long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
long currentTimeSeconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(currentTimeMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) ;
long millisUpToSecond = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(currentTimeSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// just to verify
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date(millisUpToSecond )));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it. Else, use the hard way of setting the last 3 digits to 0 manually.

```
    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

    System.out.println(ts); // 2013-09-23 15:52:45.88
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.clear();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(ts.getTime());
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    System.out.println(cal.getTime()); // Mon Sep 23 15:52:45 CEST 2013
```